# Оптимизация бота vk api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот

Пишу бота для сообщества на python. Бот работает, все хорошо, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. Бот не может обрабатывать запросы сразу от нескольких пользователей. Если 2 человека будут писать одновременно, бот игнорирует/долго обрабатывает запросы. Подскажите, можно ли как-то оптимизировать это?
Данная проблема возникает только в том случае, если запрос к боту связан с запросом в бд. Использую SQlite3. Запросы, которые не обращаются к бд выполняются отлично.

```
id_result = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?', (id,)).fetchall()
if body == 'Начать':
    if bool(id_result) == 0:
        sql = "INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (?)"
        cursor.execute(sql, (id))
        conn.commit()
        vk_session.method
    else:
        vk_session.method
```

Comment: Обрабатывать запросы асинхронно. Если желания переходить на асинхронную библиотеку нет, то можно подключить к проекту `Dramatiq` или `Celery`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, Что за асинхорнная библиотека?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там ограничение на количество обращений к API в секунду:

```
There can be maximum 3 requests to API methods per second from a client.

Maximum amount of server requests depends on the app's users amount.
If an app has less than 10 000 users, 5 requests per second, up to 100 000 – 8 requests, up to 1 000 000 – 20 requests, 1 000 000+ – 35 requests.
```

Официальные приложения от ВК давно декомпилированы и client secret'ы от них в публичном доступе. Используй их.

Comment: There can be maximum 3 requests to API methods per second from a client. Тут имеется ввиду от 1 пользователя, но проблема в том, что когда сразу 2 пользователя посылают запрос в бд, бот не справляется. Игнорирует/крашится, но без ошибок